# XORing an unsigned integer with a hexadecimal constant in C

Tags: c, file, cryptography, xor

Consider the following snippet of a C implementation for bruteforcing a cryptosystem, in which most notably the first four bytes of the ciphertext (contained in `value`) are XORed with the first four bytes of the plaintext .png file:

```
void brute_force_png()
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    unsigned int value = 0;
    unsigned int key = 0;

    file = fopen("output", "r");

    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened\n");
        return;
    }

    fread(&value, 4, 1, file);
    fread(&value, 4, 1, file);

    fclose(file);

    key = value ^ 0x474E5089;

    printf("key = 0x%x\n", key);

    decrypt(key, 0);
}
```

The line in which I'm particularly interested is:

```
key = value ^ 0x474E5089;
```

In the cryptosystem being bruteforced, we know that XORing the key with the first four bytes of the plaintext (in this case the plaintext is a .png file) gives us the first four bytes of the ciphertext. Now, according to several online sources, the "magic number" (i.e., first four bytes) of any .png file is (in hexadecimal) 0x89504E47. Why, then, shouldn't the above line be replaced by:

```
key = value ^ 0x89504E47;
```

Has this something to do with the way in which the file is read?

Comment: Please explore endianness. Do you see anything in common between your two values?

Comment: I do notice that they are pretty much the reverse of one another. Does this mean that this file is little-endian?

Comment: The first 4 signature bytes are not an `int`: they are in byte order. But read *as if* an `int` and endianness will apply. That is a function of the processor, since you read all 4 bytes into an `unsigned int`.

Comment: You're going to get some interesting results if the file isn't at least 8 bytes long....